Getting error while Running Angular migration from 9.xx to 10.xx using Nx
C:\WOA_Workspace4\CI-UI-Workspace>npx nx migrate --run-migrations=migrations.json
C:\WOA_Workspace4\CI-UI-Workspace\node_modules@nrwl\workspace\node_modules\yargs\build\lib\yargs.js:1132
throw err;
^
Error: Command failed: npm install
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
at Object.execSync (child_process.js:657:15)
at taoPath (C:\WOA_Workspace4\CI-UI-Workspace\node_modules@nrwl\workspace\src\command-line\nx-commands.js:303:21)
at Object.handler (C:\WOA_Workspace4\CI-UI-Workspace\node_modules@nrwl\workspace\src\command-line\nx-commands.js:77:19)
at Object.runCommand (C:\WOA_Workspace4\CI-UI-Workspace\node_modules@nrwl\workspace\node_modules\yargs\build\lib\command.js:196:48)
at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (C:\WOA_Workspace4\CI-UI-Workspace\node_modules@nrwl\workspace\node_modules\yargs\build\lib\yargs.js:1043:55)
at Object.get [as argv] (C:\WOA_Workspace4\CI-UI-Workspace\node_modules@nrwl\workspace\node_modules\yargs\build\lib\yargs.js:986:25)
at Object.initLocal (C:\WOA_Workspace4\CI-UI-Workspace\node_modules@nrwl\cli\lib\init-local.js:24:13)
at Object. (C:\WOA_Workspace4\CI-UI-Workspace\node_modules@nrwl\cli\bin\nx.js:40:18)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:945:30) {
status: 1,
signal: null,
output: [ null, null, null ],
pid: 19476,
stdout: null,
stderr: null
}
Node Version: 12.11.0

This github issue can be helful but make sure you don't migrate latest (3rd step of the comment I linked) but migrate to latest 11 version. Which will be 11.6.3.
Also make sure you are doing migrations with npx with node 18 and then switching back to proper node to test your environment. You also might have to delete package lock since node 18 generates lockfile version 3 and node 14 has lockfile version 1 I believe.
In that manner I successfuly upgraded form 9 to 13/14 so if there will be any problem please let me know in the comments.
So if someone still needs step by step guide:

Go for node 18
npx @nrwl/tao@latest migrate 10.4.13 or if that wont work @nrwl/tao@11.6.3 migrate 10.4.13
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npx nx migrate 11.6.3
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npx nx migrate --run-migrations
Switch node back to proper version (for angular 11 is node 12.22.12)
Delete package lock
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
and test the environment, fix some code bugs that wasn't covered by migration. If there is any additional problems let me know in the comments section

That approach will left you with some code problems because we ditch some migration steps from 9 to 10 but it will be easily fixable.
Also for node switching I used NVM. Installable from exe file or choco if you like. It makes switching node versions very easy, just one cmd command.
Useful sites to check compatibility:

Angular / Node versions support
Node top versions per major release
Nx versions for Angular versions


The issue stuck at Tao package migration. Please check below error:
Node.js version v14.15.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.19.
Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
@angular/cli migration failed, see above.
C:\CI-UI-Workspace\WOA_Workspace2\CI-UI-Workspace\node_modules@nrwl\workspace\node_modules\yargs\build\lib\yargs.js:1132
throw err;
^
Error: Command failed: npx tao migrate --run-migrations=migrations.json
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:

Just edited the thread. When I was writing I was during migration from 10 to 11 which was troublesome. Then moved back to 9 and used different approach which is now above since I edited thread (migrating from 9 to 11 straight). Then I tested my environment successfully. Please try this and get back to me in case of any errors. I will point you in the right directions since I probably encountered same problems along my way.
